# Highlight any cells with specific formula text in cell (ie =Vlookup) in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

How can I use conditional formatting to highlight any cells in a spreadsheet that have specific formula text? In my use case, I am trying to identify in a larger spreadsheet, anywhere that I have used "arrayformula." Ideally, what I want to do is to view the sheet and have any cells that have specific text inside of a formula visually highlighted. For example, if there were a row populated in C1:C through an arrayformula in C1 then only C1 would be highlighted. C2:C would not.

I have tried conditional formatting format>conditional formatting>Format cells if Text contains starts wtih arrayformula

I can use CTRL+F to search, which will highlight text which is being displayed (see images) works when toggling to display formula modes (CTRL + `)

I realize the issue is being able to specify formatting a value vs a formula in a cell and am not sure if there is a way to achieve this through a custom formula being added to the conditional formatting rules/user interface?

I believe this may be possible by using conditional formatting with a custom formula that utilizes either `isformula()` or `formulatext()` functions, but I am not sure how to implement.

I believe this type of questions can best be explained with pictures, which is why I am pasting images here.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this under `custom formula` in CF

```
=regexmatch(formulatext(a1),"(?i)arrayformula")
```

[image]